# Prioritize NHibernate Validator's validation over the built in validation?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

From this [discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/nhusers@googlegroups.com/msg13034.html) I gather that NHibernate Validator runs after the built in validation, meaning my Not Null attributes throw PropertyValueException before NHibernate Validator is even run.

Is there a way to run NHV before NH's built in validators?

I'd like to still be able to validate all dirty entities like vanilla NHV does.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the entities yourself outside of nhibernate.  Here is an example:

```
ValidatorEngine validatorEngine = new ValidatorEngine();
var nhvConfiguration = new FluentConfiguration();

nhvConfiguration.SetDefaultValidatorMode(ValidatorMode.UseExternal)
   .Register(Assembly.Load("Namespace_Where_Validations_Are_Located")
   .ValidationDefinitions())
   .IntegrateWithNHibernate
     .AvoidingDDLConstraints()
     .And
     .AvoidingListenersRegister();

validatorEngine.Configure(nhvConfiguration);

InvalidValue[] invalidValues = validatorEngine.Validate(entityToValidate);
```

Comment: Does that validate all dirty items in `entityToValidate`'s object graph?

Comment: I don't believe that it does but you can test to be sure.

Comment: Checked. It doesn't (or I must be doing something wrong). I couldn't just implement this because it skips out on some of the other dirty objects I would like validated.